# Namespace function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between these two pieces of code? Both are working perfectly, so why use .dropdown.data-api in a function? I read about namespace on the internet, but I am not clear about that. Can anyone tell me what is the use of namespace functions?

```
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api',
  function () {
    $el.parent().removeClass('open')
  })
}

$('html').on('click',
  function () {
    $el.parent().removeClass('open')
  })
}
```

Comment: Hiya amit I hope you are not talking about dropdown plugin where the first on is a standard `.on` event an http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208483/get-error-in-event-handler-for-undefined-undefined-in-chrome-and-dropdown-d soimething like this the question has a code `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespacing an event allows you to target a particular event should you wish to, say, unbind or trigger it.

Imagine you have two events of the same kind bound to the same element(s).

```
$('.something').on('click', function() { /* do something */ });
$('.something').on('click', function() { /* do something else */ });
```

Since we didn't namespace either event, it is now difficult to unbind or trigger one but not the other. Now consider:

```
$('.something').on('click.one', function() { /* do something */ });
$('.something').on('click.two', function() { /* do something else */ });
```

Because this time each event has its own namespace, we can now trigger or unbind one or the other, leaving the other untouched.

```
$('.something').off('click.one'); //unbind the 'one' click event
$('.something').trigger('click.two'); //simulate the 'two' click event
```

[**EDIT** - as @jfrej right points out below, namespaces mean you sometimes don't even need to reference the event type name. So if you had a mouseover and click event both on a single namespace, you could unbind both with `off('.namespace')`.]

Comment: interesting, i previously always did that with specifying the event method in the unbind, this seems easier.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. jQuery's documentation is here: [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Comment: great example. after reading your answer i have no doubt in my mind. thanks Utkanos.nice way to explaining

Comment: What's also very useful (and mentioned in the docs linked above) is that you can unbind all event handlers from one namespace e.g. `$('.something').off('.one');` at once

Comment: Very true. In my example I unbound namespaced events of a particular type, but yes, you can omit the event type name and just target the namespace. Worth an edit, I think.

Comment: Also, you can do `$('.something').data('events')` and each event handler will have the `namespace` attribute populated - so it's easier to distinguish between them.